# Redirecting non-SSL domain to an SSL domain with a different TLD

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'm trying to get "http://example.co.uk" *and* "https://example.co.uk" to redirect to "https://example.com".

The site "https://example.com" is set to always use HTTPS with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I have "example.co.uk" setup with an A record to go to the IP address of the server, Chromium gives an SSL error asking me if I'm sure I want to proceed when using both http and https, and Firefox shows the "Untrusted connection" page when using https (http shows the site but with non-SSL content hidden).

I tried to have "https://example.co.uk" and "http://example.co.uk" redirect to "https://example.com" with:

```
<Virtualhost example.co.uk:80>
        ServerName example.co.uk

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co.uk$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co.uk$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

..which partially works in Chromium since it redirects to a non-https version of "example.com" and it doesn't have any affect in Firefox.

The problem with this is that the https version of the site no longer works, nor does the rewrite rule above.

How can I have "https://example.co.uk" and "http://example.co.uk" go to "https://example.com" without any SSL warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get warning-free https without a valid certificate set up, and unfortunately for you that includes redirects.  You'll need to set up (with a separate IP address, SNI or a subject alt names) a properly signed certificate for your .co.uk, and make sure that your DNS is set up to point at the IP that serves it.  This may be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Currently I have only got an SSL certificate for the .com domain, so I will go ahead and get one for the .co.uk domain. The website's domain used to be .co.uk and I'm wanting the redirect so customers aren't lost and also because the .co.uk domain is high ranking on Google for search terms related to the site. 

Thanks for your answer!